# Chrome on iOS @media query has no effect with jQuery addClass

Tags: html, jquery, css, ios, media-queries

It appears to me that iOS 14.8.1 does not honor my @media query, used in conjunction with jQuery addClass, in Chrome and Safari.  Following is my code, abbreviated for clarity:

**CSS:**

```css
    .outer_div
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .inner_div
    {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 30px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: margin-left 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
        transition-delay: 1s
    }
    .inner_div.opacity_1
    {
        margin-left: 50px;
        opacity: 1
    }
    @media (max-width:600px) 
    {
        .inner_div
        {
            width:100%;
            margin-left:40px;
            margin-right:40px
        }
        .inner_div.opacity_1
        {
            margin-left:40px
        }
    }
    @media (max-width:340px) 
    {
        .inner_div
        {
            margin-left:30px;
            margin-right:30px
        }
        .inner_div.opacity_1
        {
            margin-left:30px
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```html
    <div class="outer_div">
        <div class="inner_div">
            Enough text to wrap.
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
    window.onload = function()
    {
        $('.inner_div').addClass('opacity_1');
    }
```

At a screen width of <= 600px, the margins force an inner_div width of < 100%.

Expected desktop behavior is for inner_div to fade in and shift 20px to the right. Expected iPhone behavior is for inner_div to fade in and remain fixed in position with a margin-left of 30px due to the @media query. This is intended to avoid an annoying shift in the text content of inner_div that I expect on iPhone, because the text wraps differently with a margin of 50px than it does with a margin of 30px.

Actual behavior on a desktop browser is as expected, both with normal viewing and with simulated iPhone viewing turned on.  Actual behavior on iPhone is that when the class opacity_1 is added to inner_div, its margin-left changes to 50px, and a word shifts to the next line during the transition.  So it appears to me that my @media query is being disregarded on iPhone.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your $ selector is incorrect - missing a dot.

Comment: Boiled down to the essentials, when viewing on iPhone, I want the margin-left of inner_div to be 30px, and I don't want margin-left to transition.  I found that adding "transition: margin-left 0s" to inner_div.opacity_1 in the 600px media query achieves this.  So, my problem is solved, but at this point, my original question remains.  Is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks.  It's a typo here, not in my actual code.  I'll correct.

Comment: Sorry, in my "Boiled down" comment above, I meant to say that adding "transition: margin-left 0s" to inner_div in the 600px media query achieves my desired behavior.